# Custom cursor png has blue glow

Tags: html, css, graphics

**Update: I think this issue might have to do with Mac OS X. If I hover over a darker area, the glow is correctly rendered as gray. [Testable here](http://jsfiddle.net/eNgjP/). Can somebody confirm this?**

For my HTML5-Application I wanted to use a custom cursor. I created the following png-image:

[image]

However, when I use CSS to change my cursor to this image, it gets a blue glow (this is a photo of my screen):

[image]

The code I use, is simply:

```
cursor: url('images/cursor.png') 5 5, auto;
```

Using the latest version of Chrome for Mac.

**How can I remove this weird blue glow?**

Did I incorrectly export my image to PNG (I used Fireworks)? Or did I miss something in my CSS-code? If I include the cursor-image using the `img`-tag, it is rendered correctly.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: working fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/eC3p4/

Comment: Hm, I get the blue glow there as well. What browser/OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 7. FF 23.0.1 & Chrome Version 29.0.1547.57 m. What about you?

Comment: users screen color is varying.

Comment: @Unknown I'm using Chrome 29.0.1547.57 on Mac OS X 10.8.4

Comment: @C-Link I can't imagine this being related to screen color because the png is always rendered correctly, unless I use it as a cursor in css

Comment: I guess that's because of *color combination*, change the background that try it again.

Comment: @HashemQolami You mean in the HTML/CSS? I get the blue glow [here aswell](http://jsfiddle.net/eC3p4).

Comment: @Macks please add your background-image in the fiddle as well.

Comment: @HashemQolami the background is simply white: `background: #fff;` http://jsfiddle.net/QhGgZ/

Comment: No blue to see here. Ehm, on your screen, do grayscale photographs have bluish areas?

Comment: @MrLister no, grayscale images are fine for me. The cursor png also looks fine in my graphics programm and if I include it on my webpage with a simple img-tag.

Comment: Just to check, have you double checked your usability/accessibility preferences in both Chrome and Systems Preferences, or any 3rd party mouse packages you may have installed? It sounds like a native function to make a cursor easier to find.

Answer (score 0):

your using a png, the problem would more then likely reside in transparency..

If you believe this is not the issue clear your cache and refresh the page.

Comment: Thanks Richard. Clearing the cache doesn't help. If I export my png with a white background (instead of a transparent one), it looks fine. This is not a viable solution though. :(